# How to make a 4X6 matrix from a 6X6 diagonal matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am having a diagonal matrix `A = diag(a,b,c,d,e,f)` which is a **6x6** matrix. From this I want to make **4x6** matrix specified by:

```
B(1, :) = [a b 0 0 0 0]

B(2, :) = [0 0 c 0 0 0]

B(3, :) = [0 0 0 d e 0]

B(4, :) = [0 0 0 0 0 f]
```

My logic is like this: add the two rows whose index is not divided by 3 and place it on the first row of these two... and then delete the all rows with even indices.

Comment: What have you tried? It is generally considered good practice to post your attempts as part of the question.

Comment: Your comment didn't come out correctly. Also, don't post it in the comments. There's an [edit] button on the lower left of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `for`-loop would do that:

```
diagvalues = [10:15];
A = diag(diagvalues);
B=[];

for i = 1:length(diagvalues)
    if mod(i,3) == 1
        B(size(B,1)+1,:) = A(i,:) + A(i+1,:);
    elseif mod(i,3) == 0
        B(size(B,1)+1,:) = A(i,:);
    end
end
```

You can change the diag-vector as you want.